# Get id from serializeArray

Tags: jquery, serializearray

I have the following form

```
 <form action="test.php" id="loginform" name="loginform" method="post">
     <input name="title[]" id="title1" type="text" value="" tabindex="1" />
     <input name="title[]" id="title2" type="text" value="" tabindex="2" />
     <input  name="title[]" id="title3" type="text" value="" tabindex="3" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" tabindex="4" />
 </form>
```

I am able to get the element name but not its id using this code.

```
$('#loginform').bind('submit', function() { 
    var elements = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.each(elements, function(i, element) {
        var temp = $('#' + element['name']);
        var name = this.name; alert(name);
        var id = this.id; alert(id); ///even id = this.attr("id"); not getting

        var value = this.value; 
        (temp.val() == '') ? temp.css({'background': '#FFC4C4', 'border': '1px solid #F00'}) : temp.removeClass('hightlight');
    });
    return false;
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ullasvk2000/Ct8zf/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Updating the answer on this for you:

This code:

```
var id = $(this).id;alert(id);
```

Should become this:

```
var id = $('input[name="' + name + '"]').attr("id");
alert(id);
```

See the code working here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ct8zf/5/

Please note that accoring to [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) documentation that the only elements which are serialized are the names and values.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried all possibilities but it says undefined var id = this.id;alert(id);,var id = this.attr("id");alert(id);

Comment: Thanks Mitch for your effort and time taken ,but var id = $(this).attr("id"); is also not working.

Comment: Maybe try creating a jsFiddle with with an alert, I'd be happy to take a look! :-)

Comment: Okay, so here is the ultra hacky way to do it... I would consider why you're actually serializing the array and how else you might achieve it... :-)

alert($('input[name="' + name + '"]').attr("id"));

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ct8zf/5/